# Blank item in Choice Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field

i am using SPO. I have used Alt+0129 to create a blank option in a Choice column type. Works fine for me using Firefox browser howver I have users that must use Chrome and Alt+0129 is appearing as a box. Does anyone have a suggestion for hiding the box in Chrome, or an alternative method to create a blank option in a Choice column type?

Answer (score 1):

Alt+0173 ended up working for me